# In Angular, if Login is done, the user should'nt be allowed to go Login page again until he logs out. How to implement it in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-route-guards

After login, until the user logs out , the login page route should not be accessed. how to implement it in Angular. Please give a detailed explanation with necessary code.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';
@Injectable()
export class AuthRedirectService {
  //service which helps to redirect to profile page from login/sigup page if an user is already logged in.
  constructor(private auth: AuthService, private router: Router,
              private angularfireauth: AngularFireAuth) { }
  canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
              state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | 
                                           Promise<boolean> | boolean  {
    //this.router.navigate(['/profile']);
    if (this.auth.isUserLoggedIn()==false) {
      console.log("login status from guard: ",this.auth.isUserLoggedIn);
      return true;
    }
    return false; 
  }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at route guards https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-route-guards-bf7a4ca13ae3

Comment: It just explains for guarding profile page after login. But my question is vice-versa of it.

Comment: Then just change the logic from `if (!this.auth.isAuthenticated()) {` to `if (this.auth.isAuthenticated()) {`

Comment: that is not working. I tried. Kindly help

Comment: Can you please add the code for what you've tried?

Comment: added. This is another method i tried. it is also not working

Comment: Okay, is your log statement being printed? Have you configured this guard to apply to your route?

Comment: I've configured this guard to route. But log is not printing

Comment: Okay, can you add the code for `isUserLoggedIn` as well then please

Comment: setUserLoggedIn(){
    this.isloggedIn = true;
  }

  isUserLoggedIn(): boolean {
  return this.isloggedIn;
 }

Comment: I call setUserLoggedIn in Login component. And when I check there it working fine. If user is logged in its printing true and if not false

Comment: And where have you provided the auth service? Which providers array?

Comment: In app.module.ts

Comment: You need to figure out why it's returning false then. Also, that value will be lost as soon as the user refreshes the page

Answer (score 0):

```
Include the following code in authguard.ts:

import { Injectable, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard  {
    [x: string]: any;

    constructor(private router: Router) { 

    }

    canActivate(routeerstate?: any) {
      if (!this.auth.isUserLoggedIn()) {
        this.router.navigate(['login']);  // not authenticated so always redirect to login
      } else if(routeerstate._routerState.url === '/login'){
        this.router.navigate(this.router.url]); // authenticated so stay in the current url
      }
    }
}

routeerstate._routerState.url gets you unactivated URL(to URL) i.e the url the user is trying to enter, this.router.url gets you the current URL (from URL), rest you can get it from comments in above code

export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, pathMatch: 'full',canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'authenticatedpage1', component: authenticatedPageComponent, pathMatch: 'full',canActivate: [AuthGuard] }
];
```